Material UI - Cannot find module '@mui/styled-engine'
So I started building an app with styled components, and with material UI, but I cannot get it to work. I installed everything from the docs but I keep getting the same error:
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '@mui/styled-engine'
    at webpackMissingModule (createStyled.js:12:1)
    at ./node_modules/@mui/system/createStyled.js (createStyled.js:12:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/styled.js (slotShouldForwardProp.js:5:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:22:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
    at ./src/atoms/Test/Testing.tsx (TestHeading.tsx:29:1)

I used CRA, so for fixing the webpack, i installed these 2 packages:
"customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
 "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"

and created config-overrides.js file with:
const { alias } = require('react-app-rewire-alias');

module.exports = function override(config) {
    alias({
        '@mui/styled-engine': '@mui/styled-engine-sc'
    })(config);

    return config;
};

Does anyone know what is going on?
Here is my package.json just in case:
{
  "name": "pages-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.18",
    "@mui/styled-engine": "^5.15.14",
    "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^6.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-app-rewire-alias": "^1.1.7",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^6.1.11",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  }
}

